# Code produces JSON but doesn't populate calendar

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to retrieve items from a database then load them into `fullcalendar`.

Can anybody explain why this code flashes up raw JSON, then parses it but does not populate the calendar?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
if($conn)
{        
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $sql = "SELECT id, start, end, title FROM events";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $events[] = $row; 
        }
    echo json_encode($events);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: The `exit` line kills the script. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: Looks like PHP backend code for AJAX query. Could you please show the front end part?

Comment: rickdenhaan If I take out the exit it gives  'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data.' How can I avoid the white space?

Comment: Rauli Rajande There is no front end

Comment: I changed the if($conn) to if(isset($_POST['view'])) now I just get  'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data.'

Comment: @gleb At the point where you're calling `JSON.parse()` to process this data (that's what Rauli meant by "front end"), can you check what the JSON actually is? If it's coming from this script, you may need to remove that jQuery script from the top.

Comment: @gleb "there is no front-end"...err what? Then how are you getting a calendar error? In a web app, the user-facing part which renders in the browser part is your front-end. Show your fullCalendar code where you're trying to load this data please. Also a sample of the JSON output would be useful. You say "this code flashes up raw JSON then parses it "...so you must be doing that operation somewhere, and that's the bit that's where the problem is occurring by the sound of it, so we need to see it. I don't think you need to alter anything on the PHP side by the looks of it

Comment: @ADyson'This is the whole text of index.php<?php
include("database.php");
$datetime_string = date('c',time());    
header('Content-Type: application/json');        
$result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id, start ,end ,title FROM  events");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $events[] = $row; 
        }
echo json_encode($events); 
exit;
?>
<!doctype html>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div id="calendar"></div>
</div>
</div>.'

Comment: @ADyson'This is one item of the raw JSON [{"id":"120","start":"2017-11-07 15:00:00","end":"2017-11-07 16:30:00","title":" IT class"} which is read correctly from the database

Comment: @ADyson I would give you a screenshot of the screen output but I don't know how. It is a vertical list of the events with JSON Raw Data and Headers  tabs at the top. The JSON view is the one I want to send you.

Comment: It is based on this [link](http://www.phplift.net/jquery-fullcalendar-integration-with-bootstrap-php-mysql/)

Comment: well, if that really is all your code, then yes all that script does is echo the JSON onto the page directly. The result you get is exactly what your code is expected to do. You haven't even got any JavaScript code to create a calendar, according to that. So firstly your events should be fetched from a different PHP file, and you just tell the calendar which URL to call in order to get the events. And secondly you need to use some code to actually initialise the calendar. Have you looked at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ at all? It gives you the very  basics of setting up fullCalendar.